# How to post to a friend's wall in facebook iOS SDK 3.1?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I have the SDK 3.1 working for iOS 6 for posting status updates and I have the facebook user id of the person who I want to post on their wall.

I just want it to say "hi." to just one person's wall.
I can target their feed with "/[id]/feed" but then I have to supply a graph object? if I use startForPostWithGraphPath() anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out!

First of course implement FBFriendPickerDelegate per here, unless you already have their friend ID somehow. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/filter-devices-friend-selector-using-ios-sdk/

Then the important part, how to post to friend's wall:

```
- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString* fid;
    NSString* fbUserName;

    // get facebook friend's ID from selection. just gets 1 right now.
    for (id<FBGraphUser> user in friendPickerController.selection)
    {
        NSLog(@"\nuser=%@\n", user);
        fid = user.id;

        fbUserName = user.name;
    }

    //Make the post.
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Join me!", @"message", @"http://itunes.apple.com/my-super-app", @"link", @"My Super App", @"name", nil];

    NSLog(@"\nparams=%@\n", params);

    //Post to friend's wall.
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", fid] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         //Tell the user that it worked.
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Shared"
                                                             message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invited %@! error=%@", fbUserName, error]
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alertView show];
     }
    ];

    //Close the friend picker.
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out – too bad it’s a feature that will be disabled soon, see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/ The only way left to do such will be the Feed dialog in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know how to show the feed dialog targeted to a friend's wall?

Comment: Of course, it’s right there in the docs, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ – section about parameters.

Comment: But how to I access the [_facebook dialog] function in the new sdk when I don't have a variable called _facebook and it doesn't know what class Facebook is and if I try to include facebook.h I get a ton of errors?