# Post on friend wall using Graph Api in ios not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I have get my friend id using facebook graph and post message in my friend wall not working.

```
AppDelegate *getdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

[[getdelegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",fbidstr] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

I'm using above code. please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850630/how-to-post-to-a-friends-wall-in-facebook-ios-sdk-3-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following change from 6th March 2013, posted on the list of completed changes in [the Facebook Developers' Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/):

> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**
>   We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the `target_id` user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via [user mentions tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/) or [action tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople/) will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/).